# Jquery Datatables Checkbox selected append to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

the btnSearchName will open a Modal with table of the search result, then it has checkbox per row to select, then after I click the btnSubmit, the Modal will close and must put the selected ssn_or_tin column in an input field like '123, 645, 936, 743', I already tried many codes but not working, please help

```
$('#btnSearchName').on("click", function() {
    Namestable = $('#NamesDatatable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        'select': {
            'style': 'multi'
        },
        'order': [[1, 'asc']],
        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/Home/GetAllCusname',
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.searchParameters = {};
                d.searchParameters.name = $('#txtName').val();
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                defaultContent: '',
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                'checkboxes': {
                    'selectRow': true
                },
                orderable: false
            },
            { "data": "ssn_or_tin", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "name", "autoWidth": true }
        ]
    });
});

$('#btnSubmit').on("click", function () {
    var rows_selected = Namestable.column(0).checkboxes.selected(); //i have not tested this line of code yet if it's working,
                            maybe there is another way of getting the selected checkbox, maybe by their class if they have the 'selected' class

    $.each(rows_selected, function () {
        $('#txtSSNTIN').append(
            //I don't know what code to put here, it must append the 
            'ssn_or_tin' values like '123, 953, 673' in the input field with 
             the id 'txtSSNTIN'
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have try `Onrowbound` in DataTable. You dont have to specify these things

Comment: I can't find Onrowbound on Jquery DataTables